# Hibernate/mysql connection issues

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are working on a java struts2 framework webapplication with Hibernate 3 ORM. We use mysql as our database.

We found a some DB related exceptions in logs. Connection to the database is timed out before the configured time. Here are the commons exceptions we found.

```
104343235 [pool-6-thread-19] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 100,838,460 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 100,838,461 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.myproject.model.dao.entities.EntitiesDAO.getByIds(EntitiesDAO.java:148)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 100,838,460 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 100,838,461 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor345.newInstance(Unknown Source)104343242 [pool-6-thread-16] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 100,838,544 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 100,838,544 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
104343242 [pool-6-thread-16] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 100,838,544 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 100,838,544 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3829)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2449)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 21 more
```

Everyday we are restarting our app server as a temparory fix to the issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [See Here for reference](http://www.codefin.net/2007/05/hibernate-and-mysql-connection-timeouts.html)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How you solved this?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because MySQL server terminates connections with no activity after a timeout. 
You need to add a few lines to the dbcp configuration
Try adding the following parameters :

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
testOnBorrow="true
```

How it works: The connection-pool tries running validationQuery before returning the connection. If the validationQuesry fails, dbcp discard the connection, creates a new one and return it.

Here's an example:

```
<Resource   name="jdbc/cooldatabase"
            description="Strandls.com license database"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cooldatabase?autoReconnect=true"
            username="cooluser"
            password="coolpassword"
            initialSize="0"
            maxActive="20"
            maxIdle="10"
            minIdle="0"
            maxWait="-1"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            poolPreparedStatements="true"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            logAbandoned="true"/>
```

You can find complete details here : http://amitcodes.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/16/

Comment: How to do implement the same for c3p0 connection pooling?

Comment: I have never worked with c3p0 so far, but as per the discussion, there is a property called testConnectionOnCheckout:

`<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>`

[Here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1015229) is the complete discussion: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1015229

Comment: Source : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool?_sscc=t

`testConnectionOnCheckout` Must be set in `c3p0.properties`, default value is false.
Don't use it, this feature is very expensive. If set to true, an operation will be performed at every connection checkout to verify that the connection is valid. A better choice is to verify connections periodically using `c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod`.

Comment: we are using - <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>    is this the one which you mentioned or its another one ?

Comment: My bad, c3p0.idle_test_period is the hibernate configuration key which over rides  c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod.

Comment: Dude. I told ya I never worked with c3p0. Those are clues should be enough for you to do some homework ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use connection pool with Hibernate. For example `c3p0` https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool.